# Spark Java API load file with whitespace in path

Tags: apache-spark, path, load, whitespace

I am running in a problem when i try to load a ORC/Parquet file into spark(2.2) which is located in a path that contains white spaces.

HDFS allows white spaces in directory names.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/dir\ with\ whitespace
```

However reading a File that is placed in this directory seems to be impossible with Spark. Using an inputpath with a white space causes a AnalysisException

```
final DataFrameReader reader = sparkSession.read().format("orc");
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = reader.load("[...]/tmp/dir with whitespace/abc.orc");
```

The logical plan seems to be fine, the path is quoted with backticks (`orc`.`[...]/tmp/dir with whitespace/abc.orc`). However, it can not be execute as during analyzing the plan the exception occurs. It seems to me that the path is no more quoted once the plan is rewritten from the logical to the physical path and this causes parsing issues.

Neither replacing " " with "\ " or "%20" in the path helps.

Does anyone have a hint, how to load data from a path containing white spaces?